# Parsing numbers containing commas or periods

Tags: vb.net

I have three values which need to be sorted from highest to lowest value. I use the following code which works like a charm until I want to use periods "." and commas ",". If I type "1,3" it displays as I like, but if I type "1.3" it changes to 13. My end users need to be able to use both commas and periods.

How can I fix this?

```
    Dim IntArr(2) As Decimal
    IntArr(0) = TextBox1.Text
    IntArr(1) = TextBox2.Text
    IntArr(2) = TextBox3.Text
    Array.Sort(IntArr)

    Dim highestNum As Decimal
    Dim Midelnum As Decimal
    Dim lowestNum As Decimal

    lowestNum = IntArr(0)
    Midelnum = IntArr(1)
    highestNum = IntArr(2)

    MsgBox("Highest " & highestNum)
    MsgBox("lowest " & lowestNum)
    MsgBox("middel " & Midelnum)
```

Comment: Why is your `Decimal` array named `IntArr`?  That seems very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's based on culture. I say this because if I enter numbers as you described, I get the opposite effect ("1,3" -> "13", etc).

Here's a quick way to change the values to match the current culture.

At the top of your class, put this:

```
Imports System.Globalization
```

Then, you can do this:

```
  Dim IntArr(2) As Decimal

  Dim nfi As NumberFormatInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat
  Dim sep1 As String = nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator
  Dim sep2 As String = If(sep1.Equals("."), ",", ".")
  Dim useComma As Boolean = (TextBox1.Text.Contains(",") Or TextBox2.Text.Contains(",") Or TextBox3.Text.Contains(","))

  'Replace the separator to match the current culture for parsing
  Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text.Replace(sep2, sep1), IntArr(0))
  Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text.Replace(sep2, sep1), IntArr(1))
  Decimal.TryParse(TextBox3.Text.Replace(sep2, sep1), IntArr(2))

  Array.Sort(IntArr)

  sep1 = If(useComma, ",", ".")
  sep2 = If(useComma, ".", ",")

  'Reformat the results to match the user's input
  Dim lowestNum As String = IntArr(0).ToString().Replace(sep2, sep1)
  Dim middleNum As String = IntArr(1).ToString().Replace(sep2, sep1)
  Dim highestNum As String = IntArr(2).ToString().Replace(sep2, sep1)

  Dim msg As String = "Highest: {0}" & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "Lowest: {1}" & Environment.NewLine & _
                      "Middle: {2}"

  msg = String.Format(msg, highestNum, lowestNum, middleNum)

  MessageBox.Show(msg)
```

Also, since you are using .NET, you may want to skip the VB6 way of doing things. Refer to my example to see what I've used.

Comment: Of course, if you are going to allow numbers into the thousands, then you'll need to do completely different logic instead of a simple replace.

Comment: @Chriss okay This is nice because I can use commas and periods mixedup but the output if i use periods is still in commas... what Im aiming for is that if the user enters values with commas then the out put is in commas if the input is in periods the output is in periods... but mixxing the two like you did is nice :D

Comment: In order to do that, you'll still need to do the initial replace to get your Decimal parsing to work, but then you can put it back for output.

Comment: I just edited it to show how to change it based on the user's input. You can change the `useComma` logic to determine the output separator to use.

Comment: This answer is poor.  Why all the unnecessary string manipulation??  You have the `CultureInfo` object, use it!  `Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, IntArr(0))`  This will handle a decimal point or comma depending on the culture chosen.  You can also provide a `CultureInfo` to the `String.Format` method to output decimals in a different format too:  `String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), format, IntArr(0), IntArr(1), IntArr(2))`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway It handles mixed entry the way I'm doing it. It also outputs it in a different way. The only reason culture is even coming into the question is because of what the system expects for parsing. The OP said that the user could be using a comma OR a period, and that the final result needs to be what the user put. So, it's really pointless to pass in the CurrentCulture when it already uses that! It also will not work for converting it back to how the USER entered it.

Comment: For example, for US, it expects "1.3". If I put "1,3", it turns into "13", but the OP wants BOTH to come out as "1.3", but then the sorted output needs to go back to how the user did it (ex: "1,3"). How would your way address that problem?

Comment: Yes, but if you specify the correct culture in the call to `Decimal.TryParse` it will handle commas correctly.  My example below uses the German culture which uses commas for the decimal point.  And using the culture in the `String.Format` call will output as the user expects.  It's not clear if the OP means that the users will use both cultures simultaneously or if they just need to select a culture.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway What happens when you put a decimal point instead? For testing, did you put something like "1,3", "3.4", "2,5" and have them all come out as "1,3", "2,5", "3,4" -- regardless of which country it is run in?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway It is very clear. Look up in the comments on this. "what Im aiming for is that if the user enters values with commas then the out put is in commas if the input is in periods the output is in periods"

Comment: If you input a comma as the decimal point, you would need to select the appropriate culture before calling `TryParse`, but it works.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway How would you "select" the "appropriate" culture? I'm in the US, but if I enter it with a comma as the separator, it will fail. It also does not address the mixed entry mode.

Comment: It seems odd to me that a single user would use two different decimal formats, but thanks for pointing that out, I read over it pretty fast.

Comment: I would think a properly designed app would provide some means for the user to select the culture they wish to use for their data inputs and outputs.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That is true, but I'm not assuming the application design. I'm addressing the MCVE issue presented. A proper application would know the user's culture, restrict input to the format expected for that culture, etc. In this case, it's completely arbitrary, so I did what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the hack of altering the string before saving it:

```
  TextBox.Text.Replace(".",",")
```

But if you want to show the original input you could have a variable to detect the entered character:

```
  Dim isDot As Boolean = False
   Dim number As String = TextBox.Text

   If number.Contains(".") Then
       isDot = True
   End If
```

And in the end replace it just for purposes of displaying

```
  If isDot Then
       number.Replace(",",".")
   End If
```

Comment: yeah I thought about that but i want the usser to be able to decide what they use wether that be commas or periods

Comment: Use the above method for sorting. If the user says he wants to use dots, just do a re-replace .Replace(",",".") after the sort

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer uses too much unnecessary string manipulation.  You can use the CultureInfo object to get what you need:

```
Sub Main
    Dim DecArr(2) As Decimal

    'Select the input culture (German in this case)
    Dim inputCulture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")

    Dim text1 As String = "1,2"
    Dim text2 As String = "5,8"
    Dim text3 As String = "4,567"


    'Use the input culture to parse the strings.
    'Side Note:  It is best practice to check the return value from TryParse
    '            to make sure the parsing actually succeeded.
    Decimal.TryParse(text1, NumberStyles.Number, inputCulture, DecArr(0))
    Decimal.TryParse(text2, NumberStyles.Number, inputCulture, DecArr(1))
    Decimal.TryParse(text3, NumberStyles.Number, inputCulture, DecArr(2))

    Array.Sort(DecArr)

    Dim format As String = "Highest: {0}" & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "Lowest: {1}" & Environment.NewLine & _
                            "Middle: {2}"

    'Select the output culture (US english in this case)
    Dim ouputCulture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")

    Dim msg As String = String.Format(ouputCulture, format, DecArr(2), DecArr(1), DecArr(0))

    Console.WriteLine(msg)
End Sub
```

This code outputs:

```
Highest: 5.8
Lowest: 4.567
Middle: 1.2
```

Comment: Your message is putting the Lowest into the Highest, Middle into the Lowest, and Highest into Middle. The indices should be 2, 0, 1. Also, I explained the "unnecessary string manipulation" in our conversation under my answer, including the OP's comment -- "what Im aiming for is that if the user enters values with commas then the out put is in commas if the input is in periods the output is in periods". I'm commenting here to clarify in case someone sees this and goes TL;DR on the comment chain.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that.